# How to get lazy loading image appending only once on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with a lazy load responsive piece of jQuery I'm writing. When the `div.responsive-container` is on screen then load the `<picture>` from the `<template>` element. Its working except that the image is appended multiple times in the `div.responsive-container` when I scroll. I need it only to append it once.

Here is the code I have:

**HTML**

```
<div class="responsive-container">
  <template>
    <picture>...</picture>
  </template>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  if ($('.responsive-container').is(':visible')) {
    $('.responsive-container').each(function(){
      var templateContent = $(this).find('template').html();
      console.log(templateContent);
      $(this).append(templateContent);                       
    });
  } 
});
```

Comment: You can google for jquery lazyload plugins

Comment: @Martijn This approach I'm using very simple. Should be able to get it working better with a little help. Don't want the overhead of a plugin added to the codebase.

Comment: There are manyt lightweight plugins to be found, some just take a bit more effort. They often fix problems you're not aware of yet :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Responsive lazy loading images prototype
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  $('.responsive-container').each(function(){
    var isAdded = false,
        that    = $(this);
    if (that.isInViewport()){
      if(!isAdded){
        var templateContent = that.find('template').html(),
            theImage        = that.find('img');
        that.append(templateContent);
        that.find('template').remove();     
        theImage.on('load', function(){
          if(this.complete){
            that.addClass('loaded');    
          }
        });
      }
      isAdded = true;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please note! this works on all browsers expect those which don't support the `<template>` tag